# UIKit: why would UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext use much less memory than -[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile]?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit

My app displays a bunch of images in a `UICollectionView`. When I call:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thumbnailPath];
```

my app uses around 60mb of RAM for my test set of images.

However, when I then do the following:

```
  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thumbnailPath];

  // Pre-render the image to ensure there isn't lag later.
  CGSize imageSize = image.size;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
  UIImage* preRenderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return preRenderedImage;
```

It is down to only around 15mb of RAM.

The image scale is 1.0 before and and after the pre-rendering, and size is the same, so I'm not sure what accounts for the difference in memory usage. I also tried using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 2.0);` which made no difference in memory usage.

Similar: [Why does my UIImage take up so much memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662116/why-does-my-uiimage-take-up-so-much-memory)

**Update**

Here is a dump of the image info:

```
----- original -------
CGImageGetHeight: 1024
CGImageGetWidth:  768
CGImageGetColorSpace: <CGColorSpace 0x174222e20> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)
CGImageGetBitsPerPixel:     32
CGImageGetBitsPerComponent: 8
CGImageGetBytesPerRow:      4096
CGImageGetBitmapInfo: 0x00000005
  kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask     = YES
  kCGBitmapFloatComponents   = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrderMask     = 0x00000000
  kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault  = YES
  kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big    = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big    = NO

----- pre-rendererd -------
CGImageGetHeight: 1024
CGImageGetWidth:  768
CGImageGetColorSpace: <CGColorSpace 0x174222e20> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)
CGImageGetBitsPerPixel:     32
CGImageGetBitsPerComponent: 8
CGImageGetBytesPerRow:      4096
CGImageGetBitmapInfo: 0x00002002
  kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask     = YES
  kCGBitmapFloatComponents   = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrderMask     = 0x00002000
  kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault  = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little = YES
  kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big    = NO
  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big    = NO
```

Note the difference in byte order, which makes sense because png files are big endian ([PNG file format endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384111/png-file-format-endianness)). Could the endianness be causing the excess memory usage (presumably because of a conversion before drawing)? It would be a surprise because PNGs are used all over in an iOS app.